# How to access secrets in docker-compose without storing them into a file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have create secrets on my node using Docker:

```
printf 'my-secret'  | docker secret create db -
```

To my current knowledge, they are somewhere stored inside Docker:

```
> docker secret ls
ID                   NAME      DRIVER    CREATED          UPDATED
551a770kcyaujdn...   api-key             10 minutes ago   10 minutes ago
t4ule9a75i27wl7...   db                  10 minutes ago   10 minutes ago
```

Now I want to use these secrets in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  backend:
    environment:
      API_KEY_FILE: /run/secrets/api-key
  secrets:
    - api-key
  

secrets:
  api-key:
```

However, this gives an error message on running "docker compose up":

> secrets.api-key must be a mapping

I have also tried:

```
secrets:
  api-key:
    external: true
```

But this gives another error:

> unsupported external secret

I even tried to put this secret into a file:

```
secrets:
  api-key:
    file: ../secrets/api-key
```

But the ENV-var API-KEY is still empty inside the corresponding container.

How to achieve that?

Comment: So you're using docker swarm for the secrets?

Comment: @Paolo yes. However, I use only one node at the time. So swam is not a MUST, but I read in tutorials about to enable this in order to use docker secrets without storing them plaintext in files

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you need to nest the `secrets` key in the service that needs the secrets:

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    environment:
      API_KEY_FILE: /run/secrets/api-key
    secrets:
      - api-key

secrets:
  api-key:
    file: ./api-key.txt
```

Note in this version of the YAML, the `backend.secrets` key is indented to be even with `environment`.

This was the way that you do it with a file, but you can also do it with the stored secret that you created. I think the problem there is that you used the wrong name. You named the secret `db` so you should refer to it as `db` in your compose file:

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    secrets:
      - db

secrets:
  db:
    external: true
```